# how to calculate the sum of elements other than the specified indices?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sum

I have a 3*3 array of values

```
array([[20, 10, 30],
       [35, 45, 25],
       [15, 25, 35]])
```

I want to create a function where, when I pass a number argument it should sum all the rows and column elements smaller than the elements which fall on the number.

```
def sum_con (ar,a):

    y=a-1

    z=ar[0][0]+ar[0][1]+ar[1][0]+ar[1][1]

    return z


sum_con(array,2)
>>110
```

But you can see this code is not dynamic as it is not scaleable.

Can someone provide code for doing the same functionality for n shaped array.?

Comment: Why not get the length of the columns and for each column to get the length of the row and then iterate based on that? That way, your solution will fit any size of array.

Comment: The wording of the question is still potentially confusing.  Could you also include the desired results for `sum_con(array, 0)` and `sum_con(array, 1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "other than", simply do the sum as usual and subtract/add accordingly:

```
def sum_con(a, n):
    return a.sum() - a[n].sum() - a[:,n].sum() + a[n,n]
```

This will make the n'th row and column "disappear" when summing.

For "smaller than", it's even easier:

```
def sum_con_2(a, n):
    return a[:n,:n].sum()
```

Comment: if i try for n=1 this fails

Comment: for the same array if i choose n=1 i should get 20 as result. It is coming 100

Comment: You said you want "other than" rather than "smaller than". `20` is definitely the result of "smaller than"

Comment: sorry i meant smaller than. i will edit my question too

Comment: @the second one worked, why i am not seeing it in the answers i want to upvote it.